# Android online XML parsing issue - SAX Parser

Tags: android, xml, parsing, url, sax

I am just starting out in android app development although I do have some knowledge of java.

So my app needs both `local & internet based xml files` to be parsed. I did manage to parse them locally but I have been trying for quite some time to parse the xml files on internet but no success.

I have used both `XML Pull Parser & SAX Parser`. Moreover, I have also tried multiple XML files but no progress. I am posting a sample code of `SAX Parser` consisting of one of the sample XML files on a url.

In the program, all I am trying to do is to just read a simple attribute from an element but the file can not be read.

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class WeatherXMLParsing extends Activity 
{
TextView tv;

static final String baseUrl="http://gunsnroses23.zxq.net/ak/catalog.xml";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);


    try
    {
        URL website= new URL(baseUrl);

        //setting up XMLReader & SAXParser to parse data
        SAXParserFactory spf=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp=spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr=sp.getXMLReader();
        HandlingXMLStuff doingWork= new HandlingXMLStuff();
        xr.setContentHandler(doingWork);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(website.openStream()));
        String information=doingWork.getinformation();
        tv.setText(information);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        tv.setText("Error");
    }
  }
}

public class XMLDataCollected {

String catalog=null;


public void setCatalog(String c){
    catalog=c;
}
public String datatoString(){
    return "The attribute of catalog is " +catalog;
}
}

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class HandlingXMLStuff extends DefaultHandler 
{
private XMLDataCollected info=new XMLDataCollected();
public String getinformation(){
    return info.datatoString();
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException 
        {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (localName.equals("catalog")){
            String catalog=attributes.getValue("journal");
            info.setCatalog(catalog);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Update:

I want to thank you to all those who replied to my query. Thank you so much but the problem has been resolved. There was no problem with the code. The only simple problem was the "internet" permission was not defined in AndroidManifest.xml. That is what I have been thinking after going through the code again & again. I could not find any issue since it is such a simple code but thank you, everyone.

Comment: are you parse other node of xml successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing here is from the start wrong. 
I think the best way to achieve what you want is to "Make an HTTP request with android", and after you'll get response string, you will parse it like a local one. See this post how to do a http request:

[Make an HTTP request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.cricinfo.com/rss/content/story/feeds/6.xml");//parsing a sample url
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");
int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

    if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {//first tag is item
        insideItem = true;
    }
}
}

 public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {  //open connection to url
       try {
           return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           return null;
         }
```

This certainly worked for me for parsing rss feed xml document

Comment: Also check if the link is broken // Malfunctioned url